Can't find google idp client in my google developer console
I am developing a webapplication and i am using aws cognito for user authentication. In aws cognito i configured oauth so my users are able to login into my application with google-login.
I created a google idp client in the developer console and configured the secret in cognito.
But now... about 1 year later. I logged in to my google developer console i cannot find this idp client anymore.
Was there a change? Is it somewhere in a legacy area of the developer console?
i'm quite confused at the moment
